# Website design strategy: Change content or load different HTMLs

Tags: javascript, html, web, yii

So this is kind of my first attempt at web design per se so it might be a newbie-ish question. Just to give a little background... I'm using the all time classic HTML + JS + CSS combo and Yii (PHP) as a backend with a MySQL database. I can't really tell what the site is about but the user will definitely interact with the backend and run some queries on the DB and stuff.

Right now my website is composed of 5 HTML files, each one of them has a common layout:

- Header or menu with logo and user info
- "Sub-Header" with a general info image and maybe some specific stuff
- Content specific to that HTML file
- Footer

Right now I find kinda annoying that each time I redirect the user to a different place of my site I have to check again if he's logged in, I make some use of cookies for that too, etc, etc.

I was thinking of moving my site to be a single page or template if you will and just append the (body)content of each of those files to the body of my master-page. That sounds pretty good at first thought, but are there any downsides to this or is this just how things should be done?

I've done web applications before using frameworks like Sencha and stuff and they all seem to work this way, but is this the way to go for this particular case?

**EDIT**

Also, what is the correct way to implement the single-page scenario?

- Get all the code in one HTML file and hide the stuff I don't want to show
- Remove from the view the stuff I want to hide and append the new stuff from some other HTML file.

Comment: A drawback is your site would have problems to be indexed by search engines. On my old site I had something similar to show the content of some pages in various languages, but I reverted to single pages to get a better indexing.

Comment: you can do both, opting in to single-page if JS is enabled. one caveat is with interactive widgets that use a $.ready() event to init; it doesn't re-fire when you update content, so you have to reload the plugins, and that can cause long-term leaks. newer plugins that use $.on are much better, and will work with a re-init

Comment: @dandavis my site is kinda heavy on JS though, I don't really care for users with JS disabled at this first stage. That's a nice tip there about the ready event, I didn't think of that. I'm quite sure I haven't used many (if not any) of those though. Maybe only when initialising the website itself.

Comment: the js-disabled support is more for SEO than those folks, to guarantee your content is indexable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your situation exactly. But I think I would make another PHP file in a protected area with a function like is_logged_in() or even redirect_if_not_logged_in(). Then you can include (or require) that PHP file in the other ones and just call the function.

You definitely don't want to be rewriting the same code over and over again.